# 'Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context' when passing value from one php file to another

Tags: php, html

I need to pass a value from this button (proyek.php):

```
<form method="post" action="setidproyek.php">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="idpro" value="<?php echo $list['id_proyek']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i> Buka</button>
</form>
```

To this php file (**setidproyek.php**):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION('idproyek') = $_POST['idpro'];
  header('laporanmingguan.php');
?>
```

But I got an error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Lex Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: I think you want square brackets `$_SESSION['idproyek']`

Comment: @lex, thanks dude it works, im so stupid

Comment: Not stupid dude, human. Thats why this site exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead

```
<form method="post" action="setidproyek.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="idpro" value="<?php echo $list['id_proyek']; ?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i> Buka</button>
<form>
```

Comment: still get the same error

Comment: $_SESSION["idproyek"]=$_POST['idpro']; is mentioned in the last comment